# Add max-value to hooked quantity selector in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have hooked the Quantity Selector to change the design and it works fine. But the problem is I can't set the `max value` dynamically. If I have only 2 items in the stock I need to set `max-value` as 2. Currently It's not working like that.

Following is the hook that I am using,

```
function woocommerce_quantity_input($data = null) {

global $product;
if (!$data) {
  $defaults = array(
    'input_name'   => 'quantity',
    'input_value'   => '1',
    'max_value'     => apply_filters( 'cw_woocommerce_quantity_input_max', '', $product ),
    'min_value'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', '', $product ),
    'step'         => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', '1', $product ),
    'style'         => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_style', 'float:left;', $product )
  );
}else {
  $defaults = array(
    'input_name'   => $data['input_name'],
    'input_value'   => $data['input_value'],
    'step'         => apply_filters( 'cw_woocommerce_quantity_input_step', '1', $product ),
    'max_value'     => apply_filters( 'cw_woocommerce_quantity_input_max', '', $product ),
    'min_value'     => apply_filters( 'cw_woocommerce_quantity_input_min', '', $product ),
    'style'         => apply_filters( 'cw_woocommerce_quantity_style', 'float:left;', $product )
  );
}

if ( ! empty( $defaults['min_value'] ) )
  $min = $defaults['min_value'];
else 
  $min = 1;


if ( ! empty( $defaults['max_value'] ) )
   $max = $defaults['max_value'];
else 
   $max = 15;


if ( ! empty( $defaults['input_value'] ) )
   $defval = $defaults['input_value'];
else 
   $defval = 1; 


if ( ! empty( $defaults['step'] ) )
   $step = $defaults['step'];
else 
   $step = 1

?>
<div class="woo-single-selection">
  <p>Quantity <?php //echo $product->get_stock_quantity(); ?></p>
  <div>
    <span class="woo-qty-num woo-quantity-input-number-decrement">-</span> 
    <input class="woo-quantity-input-number input-text qty text cw_qty" type="number" step="<?php echo $step ?>" value="<?php echo $defval ?>" min="<?php echo $min ?>" max="<?php echo $max ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $defaults['input_name'] ) ?>" title="<?php echo _x( 'Qty', 'Product Description', 'woocommerce' ) ?>"  pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"><span class="woo-qty-num woo-quantity-input-number-increment">+</span>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
}
```

How can set the maximum value as the available stock quantity value?

Comment: @vikrantzilpe thank you for your reply sir. I don't want to use plugins here. I just want to set the `max` value equal to the `available stock quantity value`

Comment: @vikrantzilpe It makes to add minimum and maximum value to the product. And also I found this line on the article that you shared "*The above solution will only work on the WooCommerce product page. Which means, even after placing above code snippet in functions.php file, the customer can update the quantity on Cart page. Also, it will be applied to all the product available on your store.*" I want to set the stock amount as the maximum value sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function max_quantity_single( $max, $product ) {
    $stock = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_stock', true );
    $max = $stock;  
    return $max;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max','max_quantity_single', 10, 2 );
```

Add this hook in your functions.php or plugin file.

Comment: I add it to my `function.php` and it made no changes sir. Problem remains the same.

Comment: This code works for single product page in which user did not add more than your product available product quantity.